# Rewrite random/button Javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’ve this script. It works fine in this situation, but it seems to conflict with other scripts in the site I'm working on. How can I rewrite it that it doesn't need jQuery / OnLoad?

This is what it does: the button opens a random link from an array in a new window everytime you click on it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>  

<title>TestBase</title>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
var links = [
    "http://vetteletters.nl", 
    "http://todont.co",
    "http://planetx.nl/titles"
    ];
$("#rnd_link").click(function(){
    window.open(links[Math.floor((Math.random()*3))]);    
});
});//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>

    <button id="rnd_link">Random</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: hi Zfrish tnx! I know, I'm really a beginner. But thanks for the link. I’ll try to figure it out.

Comment: I'm actually more intrigued on what conflicts you are seeing. This being so basic and harmless looking, I'm also wondering if you are doing something else that you need to be aware of for future pages / partials... JQuery is so amazingly useful I'd avoid forming habits now (early on as a newb) that will help you drastically in the long run

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var links = [
        "http://vetteletters.nl", 
        "http://todont.co",
       "http://planetx.nl/titles"
    ];

    var btn = document.getElementById('rnd_link');
    btn.onclick = function(){
       window.open(links[Math.floor((Math.random()*3))]);    
    }
}//]]>
```

Should work.

Comment: Tnx! This does the job!

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var links = [
    "http://vetteletters.nl", 
    "http://todont.co",
    "http://planetx.nl/titles"
];

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementById("rnd_link").onclick = function() {
        window.open(links[Math.floor((Math.random()*3))]);    
    };
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid using jQuery, I suggest using `window.onload` to trigger the function when the page loads.

```
window.onload = function(){ 
  // do stuff
};
```

Then in order to select a DOM element, you'll use the `getElementById()` method, then you'll add an event listener for a mouseclick:

```
document.getElementById("rnd_link").addEventListener("click", function(){
  // do stuff
});
```

Here's the MDN entry for event listeners for further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this:

Call the function when the button is clicked.

```
<button id="rnd_link" onclick="random()"></button> 

<script>
var links = [
    "http://vetteletters.nl", 
    "http://todont.co",
    "http://planetx.nl/titles"
    ];

function random(){
 window.open(links[Math.floor((Math.random()*3))]);
}

</script>
```

More info for onclick [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Comment: I believe you're missing the onclick event in your example. Did you mean to write `<button id="rnd_link" onclick="random()"></button>`?